# The element nav-item dropdown not working in laravel vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, adminlte

Im using laravel and vue js also Adminlte
In the beginning it was working but now ....

head

```
<!-- Font Awesome Icons -->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
  <!--Css-->

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

nav

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <!-- Messages Dropdown Menu -->

  <!-- Cerrar sesión menu -->
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">

    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-users-cog"></i>          
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
      <span class="dropdown-header">Cerrar sesión</span>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item">
        <form action="{{route('logout')}}" method="POST">
          {{ csrf_field() }}     
          Usuario                        
          <button type="submit" class="float-right text-muted text-sm"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt mr-2"></i> Salir  </button>
        </form>
      </a>          
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-widget="control-sidebar" data-slide="true" href="#"><i
        class="fas fa-th-large"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

scripts

```
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
```

it shows me: DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://x.x.x.x:8000/js/popper.js.map
data-toggle="dropdown" does not show the elements

in components app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

require('./components/Example');

import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';

Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect);
```

**The problem comes when i used npm run dev the app.js generated makes it doesn work, any idea**

Comment: please share your script

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim
 which one of them

Comment: of vue instance or the component that uses a dropdown

Comment: it work, but app.js create a problem

Comment: i need your own scripts

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem. The reason which causes this is AdminLTE template and Vue.js also includes Bootstrap and they collide. So you have to comment out or delete the Bootstrap 4 script tag, this line:

```
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

This line is already redundant.